# reinterpret_cast or C Style type casting

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

Should be prefer reinterpret_cast over C style casting. Please explain.

Which one should be preferred if one has to choose between **reinterpret_cast** and **c style casting**

Comment: Consider removing tag c and adding tag c++.

Comment: It's like trying to pick the lesser of two evils. If you *need* it (like when e.g. calling [`istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)) then you should prefer `reinterpret_cast`, but in almost all other cases I would say that if you need to do such a cast you're doing something wrong. Casting like that is definitely a [*code smell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Answer (score 2):

Casts should be used rarely, and cautiously, and it is a lot easier to spot when you're abusing the system if you write:

```
char *x = const_cast<char *>(some_const_char_pointer_expression);
```

than if you disguise it with:

```
char *x = (char *)some_const_char_pointer_expression;
```

So, use the explicit, controlled, verbose notation because it encourages you to avoid casts, and to use the correct, precise cast when you must use one.

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity15/sec15-paper-lee.pdf It's about a "bad-casting" detection tool  [CaVer]. In addition to the basic function as outlined in the paper, it would be interesting to see if CaVer's implementation of RTTI-like data [used by it internally] could be adapted so that it could be used as a [faster] alternative to the conventional [string based] RTTI information

Answer (score 0):

C style cast is more general. It 'chooses' from `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `const_cast` with `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, then `dynamic_cast` with `const_cast` and finally `reinterpret_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` with `const_cast`. So, as you see, there is pretty much difference between c-cast and `reinterpret_cast`, as C-cast cast goes with static and dynamic cast first.

If you write in C++, you should prefer one of casts above instead of C-style cast. They are more explicit. But C-style cast is not a very-very-very bad style.

Comment: C-style casting *can* be "very-very bad" as it can cast away const-correctness without warnings.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Edited my answer, thank you.